# How to create a virtual environment for a specific version of Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using a Macbook. It came with python 2.7.6 installed. I manually installed python 3.4. I develop websites using django. I have only used python 3 and when I work on a project, I simply put it inside a virtual environment.

For instance, I have a project using django-1.8 and python-3.4. I used the following command to create the environment:

```
python3 -m venv myvenv
```

After that I installed django and other packages inside of this environment.

However, I want to work on another project using python 2.7. **How do I create an environment for python 2.7** and install packages inside of that, so that my other projects remain separate and workable at the same time?

Also, is this the best way to do things? Am I going to mess something up if I continue like this?

**Edit:** I tried a solution from another question. I ran the following command on the terminal:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash:syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

Also, I tried installing virtualenv using pip running this command:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

It says pip is not found which is weird as I have used pip countless times before inside my virtual environments. Am I making a stupid mistake?

Comment: @EliKorvigo - I took a look at that question and edited mine.

Comment: No `<` and `>` around path

Answer (score 4):

When you use `python -m venv` the virtual environment will be created the Python interpreter you used to invoke to command.

To create a virtualenv to a specific interpreter, just use it to run `venv` module using this interpreter:

```
 /path/to/python3.x -m venv
```

`venv` module is not available for older Python interpreters. For those you need to install a separate virtualenv package. [The actual installation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) depends on your operating system.

The command is then like:

```
 virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/myuser/myvenvfolder
```